# Java Path error hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I have java install in my system and the path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/jre/bin/java , but when i am going to install hadoop, and want to format namenode then it showing the incorrect java installed error.

can any 1 help for installing java or have to install another java on the same.

Comment: I'm worry the question doesn't contain enough detail. E.g. what version of hadoop on what platform and how are you installing, or what is the exact error message.

Comment: I I want to install hadoop 2.7 version on REHL 6. and i have install hadoop properly , but when I have use to format namenode first time it showing error like incorrect java installed.

Answer (score 0):

put entry of java home 
in .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/jre
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

in hadoop-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
```

Note- check java path should be set or not

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
java -version
```